# Android NFC library - Command not recognized

Tags: texas-instruments, android, nfc

To access more than 2kb of data from TI Rf430 transponder IC, a custom command (0xC0) in specific format needs to be sent. On sending the custom command, command not recognized (0x01) is the response received.

Custom command array => {flag, command, manufacturer code, Block Address LSB, Block Address MSB}. Does Android NFC library supports custom commands as mentioned above?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the NFC library supports sending custom commands to NFC tags.

Your TI RF430 seems to be a [ISO/IEC 15693 NFC tag](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas834c/slas834c.pdf).

From the [Android's advanced NFC documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc), in  "Table 1. Supported tag technologies", you should use the NfcV class and in particular, [the transceive method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html#transceive(byte[])) to send custom commands.

If you want to use another type of NFC card, you may have to use one of the following transceives commands to interact with them.

- [NfcA transceive(byte[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA#transceive(byte[]))
- [NfcB #transceive(byte[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcB#transceive(byte[]))
- [IsoDep transceive(byte[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep#transceive(byte[]))